# Embedded Derby Db in a Spring app on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, derby

I'm trying to get an embedded Derby db running on a Tomcat/Spring application.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby:pepper" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="50" />
</bean>
```

When I run this, I'm getting the following error:

> org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException:
>   Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (Database
>   'WEB-INF/pepper' not found.)

I've tried the `pepper` folder at both `%webapp_root%/pepper` and `%webapp_root%/WEB-INF/pepper`

Suggestions?

Comment: Is is a read only database that you load from the classpath? If not, where are the database files supposed to be stored?

Answer (score 2):

If you're deploying a web app to Tomcat, I'd recommend setting up a [JNDI connection pool](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) and using Spring's JndiObjectFactoryBean:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/blah"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to replace url with `jdbc:derby:pepper;create=true`